# Override the Query String using a Servlet Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a requirement where I need to to decrypt the query string. I am planning to do it via Servlet Filter and extending HttpServletRequestWrapper as shown below.

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "urlDecryptionFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class UrlDecryptionFilter implements Filter {
    static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest)request);
        }

        public String getQueryString() {
            //here i put the logic to transform the existing string
            return "quertStr=modified";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. I would appreciate if anyone can point in the right direction.

Comment: what the error ? Can you give more info ?

Comment: There is no error, but I don't see the query string being replaced, it still has the old one.

Comment: Can you show the code which is making you believe that it is not working? I mean the code where you are calling the query string.

Comment: As you notice I defined this filter at root, so any request I make for e.g http://<my_server>/request_uri?somequery_string, I would expect it to be  http://<my_server>/request_uri?quertStr=modified but that's not the case.